# Rails with puma doesn't work for me. (Using docker)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backend, puma, rails-api

I'm using Docker for my development environment.
And currently I'm using 5 containers which are:
 - Postgres
 - Redis
 - Rails API
 - Sidekiq
 - Nginx
So as you see here, I'm using Rails API for any XHRs fired from my webapp served by nginx.
And now I'm trying to introduce WebSocket as well, but I just realized that my Rails API was using 'thin' instead of 'puma'
So I switched it to use puma, and now WebSocket works great, but now XHR fired to the RailsAPI server not returning (rendering) any responses.

I do see some message after running docker-compose saying:

```
apiDevelopemnt_1| Cannot render console from 172.17.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
```

Is there any config that I'm missing for 'puma' so that it works fine as API server?

Comment: Thin uses EventMachine, Puma doesn't. Does your XHR code require EventMachine? If so, it would fail (the machine isn't running)... Consider looking into this possibility and consider avoiding the EventMachine code - if your code is hijacking the HTTP connection and handling it on it's own, it might run into bigger issues as app infrastructure moves deeper into the HTTP/2 world.

Comment: Omg! Thanks for the reply! And Thanks for explaining how thin works! I'll take a look if my Rails App needs EventMachine to handle XHR. (But I don't know how I can tell...) Could you give me some hint or example of Rails-handling-XHR-with-Event-Machine? Thanks in advance!!